# how many numbers between 1 to 10 billion contains 14

Tags: c#, algorithm, api, counter

i tried this code but it takes so long and I can not get the result

```
    public long getCounter([FromBody]object req)
    {
        JObject param = Utility.GetRequestParameter(req);
        long input = long.Parse(param["input"].ToString());
        long counter = 0;
        for (long i = 14; i <= input; i++)
        {
            string s = i.ToString();
            if (s.Contains("14"))
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

please help

Comment: Do you want to get the info of how many numbers contain the "14" or how many times the numbers include "14"? Because the number 1414 contains it two times.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko 1414 will be count only 1

Comment: what about 140? will you need to count them?because the question is not clear enough

Comment: @PlexisPlexis yes i will count 140, 1414, 1014, 10014000, and any number contains 14

Comment: You may ask your question at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute the count of numbers of a given length ending in 1, 4 or something else that don't contain 14. Then you can extend the length by 1.

Then the count of numbers that *do* contain 14 is the count of all numbers minus those that don't contain a 14.

```
private static long Count(int len) {
   long e1=0, e4=0, eo=1;
   long N=1;
   for (int n=0; n<len; n++) {
       long ne1 = e4+e1+eo, ne4 = e4+eo, neo = 8*(e1+e4+eo);
       e1 = ne1; e4 = ne4; eo = neo;
       N *= 10;
   }
   return N - e1 - e4 - eo;
}
```

You can reduce this code a little, noting that `eo = 8*e1` except for the first iteration, and then avoiding the local variables.

```
private static long Count(int len) {
   long e1=1, e4=1, N=10;
   for (int n=1; n<len; n++) {
       e4 += 8*e1;
       e1 += e4;
       N *= 10;
   }
   return N - 9*e1 - e4;
}
```

For both of these, `Count(10)` returns 872348501.

Answer (score 9):

We can examine all non-negative numbers < 10^10. Every such number can be represented with the sequence of 10 digits (with leading zeroes allowed).

**How many numbers include 14**

Dynamic programming solution. Let's find the number of sequences of a specific length that ends with the specific digit and contains (or not) subsequence 14:
[image]

`F(len, digit, 0)` is the number of sequences of length `len` that ends with `digit` and do not contain 14, `F(len, digit, 1)` is the number of such sequences that contain 14. Initially `F(0, 0, 0) = 1`. The result is the sum of all `F(10, digit, 1)`.

C++ code to play with: https://ideone.com/2aS17v. The answer seems to be 872348501.

**How many times the numbers include 14**

First, let's place 14 at the end of the sequence:

```
????????14
```

Every '?' can be replaced with any digit from 0 to 9. Thus, there are 10^8 numbers in the interval that contains 14 at the end. Then consider `???????14?`, `??????14??`, ..., `14????????` numbers. There are 9 possible locations of 14 sequence. The answer is 10^8 * 9 = 90000000.

---

[Added by Matthew Watson]

Here's the C# version of the C++ implementation; it runs in less than 100ms:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int M = 10;
            int[,,] f = new int [M + 1, 10, 2];

            f[0, 0, 0] = 1;

            for (int len = 1; len <= M; ++len)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d <= 9; ++d)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
                    {
                        f[len,d,0] += f[len - 1,j,0];
                        f[len,d,1] += f[len - 1,j,1];
                    }
                }
                f[len,4,0] -= f[len - 1,1,0];
                f[len,4,1] += f[len - 1,1,0];
            }

            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
                sum += f[M,i,1];

            Console.WriteLine(sum); // 872,348,501
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SomeshSharma, No, 10000000000 has eleven digits.

Comment: The `872348501` answer appears to be correct (corroborated by my brute force approach - see below!)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a C# implementation to your answer.

Comment: I think you don't need F(len, d, 1), since you can count the numbers which contain 14 by subtracting sum(F(len, d, 0) for d = 0..9) from 10^10-1.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a *brute force* solution it could be something like this (please, notice, that we should avoid *time consuming* string operations like `ToString`, `Contains`):

```
  int count = 0;

  // Let's use all CPU's cores: Parallel.For 
  Parallel.For(0L, 10000000000L, (v) => {  
    for (long x = v; x > 10; x /= 10) {
      // Get rid of ToString and Contains here
      if (x % 100 == 14) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count); // We want an atomic (thread safe) operation

        break;
      }
    }
  });

  Console.Write(count);
```

It returns `872348501` within **6** min (Core i7 with 4 cores at 3.2GHz)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

My parallel code calculated the result as `872,348,501` in 9 minutes on my 8- processor-core Intel Core I7 PC.

(There is a much better solution above that takes less than 100ms, but I shall leave this answer here since it provides corroborating evidence for the fast answer.)

---

You can use multiple threads (one per processor core) to reduce the calculation time.

At first I thought that I could use `AsParallel()` to speed this up - however, it turns out that you can't use `AsParallel()` on sequences with more than 2^31 items.

(For completeness I'm including my faulty implementation using AsParallel at the end of this answer).

Instead, I've written some custom code to break the problem down into a number of chunks equal to the number of processors:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int numProcessors = Environment.ProcessorCount;

            Task<long>[] results = new Task<long>[numProcessors];

            long count = 10000000000;
            long elementsPerProcessor = count / numProcessors;

            for (int i = 0; i < numProcessors; ++i)
            {
                long end;
                long start = i * elementsPerProcessor;

                if (i != (numProcessors - 1))
                    end = start + elementsPerProcessor;
                else // Last thread - go right up to the last element.
                    end = count;

                results[i] = Task.Run(() => processElements(start, end));
            }

            long sum = results.Select(r => r.Result).Sum();

            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        static long processElements(long inclusiveStart, long exclusiveEnd)
        {
            long total = 0;

            for (long i = inclusiveStart; i < exclusiveEnd; ++i)
                if (i.ToString().Contains("14"))
                    ++total;

            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The following code does NOT work because `AsParallel()` doesn't work on sequences with more than 2^31 items.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbersContaining14 =
        from number in numbers(0, 100000000000).AsParallel()
        where number.ToString().Contains("14")
        select number;

    Console.WriteLine(numbersContaining14.LongCount());
}

static IEnumerable<long> numbers(long first, long count)
{
    for (long i = first, last = first + count; i < last; ++i)
        yield return i;
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but it doesn't make a big difference

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I guess you have a slow PC... It takes less than 10 mins on mine. It will in fact be faster by approximately the number of processor cores you have.

Comment: I mean that the calculation is enough fast to not make a great difference if done ina multithread version, the result takes still too long

Comment: @MarcoSalerno You should really define what "too long is" in your OP, since it would appear to be part of the requirement.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Oh - well in that case how do you know it isn't fast enough? I assumed that you were the OP because only the OP would know such details... Perhaps 10 minutes calculation time would be fine (although there is clearly a much better solution that take less than 100ms!)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to calculate the answer is,
You can fix 14 at a place and count the combination of the remaining numbers right to it,
and do this for all the possible positions where 14 can be place such that the number is still less than 10000000000,Lets take a example,

***14*****,

Here the '*' before 14 can be filled by 900 ways and the * after 14 can be filled by 10^5 ways so total occurrence will be 10^5*(900),

Similarly you can fix 14 at other positions to calculate the result and this solution will be very fast O(10) or simply O(1), while the previous solution was O(N), where N is 10000000000

Comment: Let's take a `0-10000` range. According to your suggestion the answer is `300`. But don't you think you count `1414` twice? The answer should be `299`. [Check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IAiK4L)

Comment: You don't take into account the repetitions and you are counting some numbers past ten billion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that in each 1000 (that is from 1 to 1000 and from 1001 to 2000 etc)
the 14 is found: 19 times  so when you receive your input divide it by 1000 for example you received 1200 so 1200/1000
the result is 1 and remainder 200, so we have 1 * 19 "14"s and then you can loop over the 200.

you can extend for 10000 (that is count how many "14"s there are in 10000 and fix it to a global variable) and start dividing by 10000 then and apply the equation above, then you divide the remainder by 1000 and apply the equation and add the two results.

You can extend it as the fact that for all hundreds (that is from 1 to 100 and from 201 to 300) the "14" is found only 1 except for the second hundred (101 to 200).